# complexity of constructing an inverted index list

Tags: string, performance, algorithm, optimization, inverted-index

Given `n` strings `S1, S2, ..., Sn`, and an alphabet set `A={a_1,a_2,....,a_m}`. Assume that the alphabets in each string are all distinct. Now I want to create an inverted-index for each `a_i (i=1,2...,m)`. My inverted-index has also something special: The alphabets in `A` are in some sequential order, if in the inverted-index a_i has included one string (say `S_2`), then `a_j (j=i+1,i+2,...,m)` don't need to include `S_2` any more. In short, every string just appears in the inverted list only once. My question is how to build such list in a fast and efficient way? Any time complexity is bounded?

For example, `A={a,b,e,g}, S1={abg}, S2={bg}, S3={gae}, S4={g}`. Then my inverted-list should be:

```
a: S1,S3
b: S2     (since S1 has appeared previously, so we don't need to include it here)
e: 
g: S4
```

Comment: Just wondering: is there any reason S4 wouldn't be under index 'a'? Is the index supposed to be balanced in some way? If not, it seems like it would suffice to look at the first character of each string and put it under that index. Maybe I'm not understanding the problem though.

Comment: Thats my problem. Now fixed, Thanks!

Comment: Not in all the cases, if `S3={gae}`

Comment: I think I understand now--in that case, it seems like Dante has your answer. The only optimization I can think of would be to stop scanning through a particular string if you encounter the least character of the alphabet.

Comment: The point is that the number of strings is much larger than the number of alphabets. So is there some way to improve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, a straightforward solution is:

```
for each string in n strings
    find the "smallest" character in the string
    put the string in the list for the character
```

The complexity is proportional to the total length of the strings, multiplying by a constant for the order testing.

If there is a simple way for testing, (e.g. the characters are in alphabetical order and all lower-case, a < will be enough), simply compare them; otherwise, I suggest using a hash table, each pair of which is a character and its order, later simply compare them.